# Debug Real-time Android with Cardboard, Google VR, RemoteUnity5

Tags: unity3d

Тема для тех, кому необходима отладка в реальном времени в Unity (что отображается на вашем компьютере то и в телефоне, при запуске проекта в Unity), особенно с проектами VR,AR,MR, с использованием UnityRemote5 не работает акселерометр и гироскоп, (не работают повороты и обзорность 360) покажу как это исправить в Cardboard и GoogleVR.

Answer (score 0):

Прежде всего начну с установки UnityRemote5 (Спасибо Алексею Шиманскому)

1. На телефоне в настройках Developer Options (если открыть под рутом)    находим опцию Debugging - Android debugging.
   Скачиваете на телефоне UnityRemote 5 (через google play) и    устанавливаете её.
2. На ПК устанавливаете Android SDK и JDK. Второе вроде не обязательно,    но на всякий случай надо.
3. В Unity в `Edit` → `Preferences` → `External Tools` прописываете путь к    Android SDK и JDK.
4. В Unity в `Edit` → `Project Settings` → `Editor` устанавливаете `Unity    Remote` в значение  `Any Android Device`.
5. В `Unity` в пункте `File` → `Build Settings` — добавляете свою сцену и    переключаете платформу на `Android`.
   Теперь подсоединяете телефон к ПК, на телефоне запускаете UnityRemote и пока он запущен в Unity нажимаешь Play.

Теперь необходимо создать в `Unity` скрипт с названием `GyroscopeEnable.cs` и наполнить его содержимым:

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR

 using UnityEngine; 
 using System.Collections;

 public class GyroscopeEnable : MonoBehaviour {    
    private Gyroscope gyro;

     void Start () {
         if (SystemInfo.supportsGyroscope) {
             gyro = Input.gyro;
             gyro.enabled = true;
         }
     }
  }
#endif
```

Прикрепите этот скрипт к новому GameObject в редакторе.

(Если у вас Cardboard) перейдите в папку  `Assets/Cardboard/Scripts/VRDevices`
 и найдите скрипт с названием `UnityEditorDevice.cs` и измените строку следующим образом:

было  `if (/*Cardboard.SDK.UseUnityRemoteInput &&*/ RemoteCommunicating ) {`

стало  `if (RemoteCommunicating) {`

(Если у вас GoogleVR) перейдите в папку `Assets\GoogleVR\Legacy\Scripts\Internal\VRDevices`
 и найдите скрипт с названием `EditorDevice.cs` и измените строку следующим образом:

было  `if (GvrViewer.Instance.UseUnityRemoteInput && RemoteCommunicating) {`

стало  `if (RemoteCommunicating) {`

Сохраните изменения и запускайте (Подключаете телефон к компьютеру, скачиваете и запускаете приложение на телефоне - `UnityRemote5`, в `Unity` нажимаете `Play`).

P.S. качество графики можете установить в `Edit` → `Project Settings` → `Editor` → `Resolution` → `DownSize/Normal`

(Источник http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/985989/google-cardboard-not-move-the-camera-when-im-using.html)